# Unable to capture objects in android emulator but same is working fine in real device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview, appium, katalon-studio

I want to automate a hybrid mobile app built in Cordova using emulators. I am not able to capture the elements on an emulator. While capturing the elements,i am getting the "element retrieved is not found" error when the script is executed. Along, the elements on a HTML panel object are never captured. I made the script on the real device with same specification as my emulator and it worked like a charm there. But the emulator always behaves unexpected.

Any help will be highly appreciated. I am really stuck in this issue.

Comment: might me a problem in the xml layout.. try changing `</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>` if you have one... to `</RelativeLayout>`

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be in your Gradle files: Try this

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```